# Keyboard shortcut for "Open in Git Bash" in GitHub Desktop using Finnish/Swedish keyboard layout

Tags: github-desktop

Under "Repository" the shortcut is shown as Ctrl+` but as the back tick (grave accent) character is typed with Shift+´ in Finnish/Swedish keyboard layout this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to use Ctrl+§ but with no success. Is there some way to change the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that **Ctrl+`** shortcut can be executed by pressing **Ctrl+ö** on keyboard using Finnish/Swedish layout.